# Variance Formula

Tags: probability, invariance

for the variance formula $\text{var}(X) = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$
how are you suppose to work out $E[X^2]$ given the interval $[0,1]$ and $E[x]= 1/2$

Comment: You need to know more about the distribution than just the interval and the expected value.  Is $X$, for example, uniform on the interval $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine $E[X^{2}]$ without more information. For $f_{1}(x) = 1$, we have that
$$
E[X] = \int_{0}^{1} x f_{1}(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx = \left. \frac{1}{2} x^{2} \right|_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
and
$$
E[X^{2}] = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} f_{1}(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} \, dx = \left. \frac{1}{3} x^{3} \right|_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
For $f_{2}(x) = 12 (x - \frac{1}{2})^{2}$, we have that
$$
E[X] = \int_{0}^{1} x f_{2}(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} 12 x (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^{2} \, dx = \left. \frac{x^{2} (6 x^{2} - 8 x + 3)}{2} x^{2} \right|_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
and
$$
E[X^{2}] = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} f_{2}(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} 12 x^{2} (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^{2} \, dx = \left. \frac{x^{3} (12 x^{2} - 15 x + 5)}{5} \right|_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = \frac{2}{5}.
$$

Comment: $f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\textrm{ when } x<0,\\
x^2(3-2x) &\textrm{ when } 0\leq x \leq 1,\\
1 &\textrm{ when } x>1.
\end{cases}$

Comment: thats the $f(x)$ value in the question

Comment: You give a cumulative distribution function (CDF), not a probability density function (PDF). Let $F(x)$ be the function you gave and $f(x)$ be its derivative. You can compute

Comment: so $F(x) =$ the above CDF ... whilst $f(x) = 6x(1-x)$ ??

Comment: Correct. Then evaluate the integral $$E[X^{2}] = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} f(x) dx$$. You can tell that $F(x)$ is a CDF because it does not integrate to 1, while $f(x) = F'(x)$ does.

Comment: so we integrate $(x^2)*(6x-6x^2)$ between $[0,1]$ which equals $3/10$ hence $E[X^2]$ = $3/10$ ??

Comment: That is the answer that I got.

Comment: Thankyouuuuuuu :D ...one last question, if i was to find the variance of x for this question would it be $3/10 - (1/2)^2 = 1/20$

Comment: Looks correct to me.